# Two axis in one excel diagram

Tags: c#, .net, excel, charts

I am writing an excel file from my c# applicaiton that contains data and a chart. There are two data series (lines) displayed in the chart. One containing values from 10-300, the other one 1-10. Now I want tu use a secondary axis (usually drawn on the left side). How can I achieve this?

If I just set the `chart.UseSecondaryAxis` I get an excepetion telling me that '"Can's set to secondary axis when no serie uses the primary axis"'.

I am using C# (4.0) and the EPPlus library.

Thanks for any help

Mario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hava bad habit of answering my own questions:

Example #9 Sample9.cs shows the answer:

```
  var chart2 = firstChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add( eChartType.LineMarkers );

  ser = ( chart2.Series.Add( "O3:O10","D3:D10", dataRowIdx ) ) as ExcelChartSerie );
  ser.Header = "OtherLine";
  chart2.UseSecondaryAxis = true;
```

The first line does the trick. You have to create a second charttype, although it can be of the same type as `firstChart`.

Mario

Comment: "I hava bad habit of answering my own questions:" That's not a bad habit :D at least not on SO I think.

Comment: @mario please share here how can we draw the secondary Y-Axis against the existing data for  X-Axis & Y-Axis, instead of plotting a new series for a second Y-axis. ____ say I need to plot with value_1,value_2 and TimeReceived such that  `value_1 is in X-Axis, value_2 in Y-Axis and TimeReceived in second Y-Axis.`

Comment: @jAntoni; you would have to split up the series in two distinct series and then plot to charts as I showed above.

Comment: @jAntoni: or if you can do it in excel, open the excel file and look a the resulting xml, this usually points toward the solution.